# I have problem with a function html+jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have this function called by clicking a button:

```
$("#pulsanteNuovaCategoria").on('click', function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var categoria = new FormData();
  categoria.append("nome", $("#nomeNuovaCategoria").val());
  categoria.append("descrizione", $("#descrizioneNuovaCategoria").val());

  $.ajax({
      url: '../php/model.php?az=nuovaCategoria',
      data: categoria,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      $('.archi').append("<div class='accordion' id='accordionExample'><div class='card'><div class='card-header' id='headingOne'><div class='row'><div class='col-1'><h4>" + data.num + "</h4></div><div class='col-8'><h4 class='mb-0'><a href='#' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapse" + data.archivio_id + "' aria-expanded='false' id='nomeCategoria" + data.archivio_id + "' aria-controls='collapseOne'>" + data.archivio_nome + "</a></h4></div><div class='col-1'><h4 class='mb-0'><a href='#' data-id='" + data.archivio_id + "' class='editaCat' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modaleEditaCategoria' id='editCategoriaGenerale" + data.archivio_id + "'><i data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='modifica " + data.archivio_nome + "' class='far fa-edit'></i></a></h4></div><div class='col-1'><h4 class='mb-0'><a href='#' data-id='" + data.archivio_id + "' class='deleteCat' id='deleteCategoriaGenerale" + data.archivio_id + "'><i data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Cancella categoria generale' class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></a></h4></div></div></div><div id='collapse" + data.archivio_id + "' class='collapse' aria-labelledby='headingOne' data-parent='#accordionExample'><div id='descrizioneCategoria" + data.archivio_id + "' class=card-body'>" + data.archivio_descrizione + "</div></div></div></div>");
      $("#nomeNuovaCategoria").val("");
      $("#descrizioneNuovaCategoria").val("");
      $("#modaleNuovaCat").modal('hide');
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert("Qualcosa è andato storto.");
    });
});
```

This function create dynamically an entire snippet of html with an edit button completed with data-id, class and id. The important element is `class='editaCat'`.

Now in the same session, I want to click in this dynamic edit button and call a second function linked with `class='editaCat'` this:

```
$(".editaCat").on('click', function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  var idCat = this.getAttribute('data-id');

  $.ajax({
      url: '../php/model.php?az=editCategoria&id=' + idCat,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      $("#editaNomeCategoria").val(data.archivio_nome);
      $("#editaDescrizioneCategoria").val(data.archivio_descrizione);
      $("#pulsanteEditaCategoria").attr("data-id", data.archivio_id);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert("Qualcosa è andato storto.");
    });
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it will work instead of using directly click event use this for dynamically created html –

```
$(document).on('click', '.editaCat', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var idCat = this.getAttribute('data-id');

  $.ajax({
      url: '../php/model.php?az=editCategoria&id=' + idCat,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      $("#editaNomeCategoria").val(data.archivio_nome);
      $("#editaDescrizioneCategoria").val(data.archivio_descrizione);
      $("#pulsanteEditaCategoria").attr("data-id", data.archivio_id);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert("Qualcosa è andato storto.");
    });
});
```

Comment: try this it will work instead of using directly click event use this for dynamically created html

Comment: Work!!!
Great!!you say why?
with (document) jquery take all the document?? make a refresh? I don't understand...

Comment: for already existing html the function you have developed will work fine whereas for dynamically created html we need to bind the code with new html which is created so we have to use $(document). which binds the jquery with newly created html :)

Comment: Thank you very much